# How to apply grain texture effect in GIMP

Tags: gimp, effects, texture, plugin

I am trying to follow https://medium.com/google-design/salt-pepper-the-art-of-illustrating-texture-c962dc67cc35 to add material design effect to my project in GIMP.

But the tutorial is specifically for Adobe Photoshop and so I got stuck on step 4, since GIMP does not have a grain texture effect.

How can I apply a grain texture effect in GIMP? Is there any plugin or method of doing it in GIMP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Put your shape layer inside a layer group**  (Layer>New Layer Group; drag the layer onto the group in the layers list).  This group will hold your shape and any textures we add.

[image]

2. **Make a new transparent layer** in the layer group on top of your shape layer.  This is the layer we're going to put the texture on.

[image]

3. **Set the layer Mode from "Normal" to "Soft Light"**.
4. With the new transparent layer selected, **draw the gradient you want** using the gradient tool (click and drag from the start to the end of where you want your gradient to be).  I'll do a simple black/white gradient.  Now we have a gradient, but no texture!

[image]

4. **Run Filters>Noise>Spread** to randomly move the pixels of our gradient around.  Set the amount to something large (like 100) for more effect.

[image]

5. If you want slightly more realistic grain, use **Filters>Blur>Gaussian Blur (1-3px) then Filters>Enhance>Sharpen (set to 50+%)**. This keeps the grain from being just 1px noise.

[image]

You can extend this even more by adding multiple grain layers, different blend modes, or adding grain from a texture image.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very interesting. Might better work on small pieces. I found out that if texture isn't visible enough, you can improve it with a brush like Chalk 2, and drawing on the gradient. Then as said, playing with filters.

Answer (score 1):

Add a layer, fill with *Filters>Noise>HSV Noise*, then either:

- You use one of several modes (darken only, multiply, divide, overlay, soft light... ) and adjust opacity
- You use the noise layer as a bump map, using *Filters>Map>Bump map*, or as part of a more complex process that uses *Filters>Light and shadow>Lighting effects*